# Revell 6 bootloader won't unlock

Tags: bootloader

Cant get the bootloader to unlock to save my life so I can root I am a newb so I mean any help would be great because I can't get it to reboot all the way up now

Comment: I can't find any reference to a Revell 6. There's a Revvl 6 but that's an android phone ("and so I can root" makes it a possibility) - and off topic for our site. That said, there's not really enough detail to answer even if it *was* a question about a computer

Comment: Yeah it's a TMobile android revell6 phone

Comment: And if he doesn't want questions asked on this site about phones then he doesn't need to provide a link here from the android playstore and I'll email him personally seeing how you removed my question and run this site I'm guessing

Comment: Reason you don't have many members now people like u

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic is worth a read

Comment: Seeing how a phone is the newest and up to date computers there is on the planet and the others are becoming obsolete you would think you would want to have questions about any and all software and all computers

Comment: Well you have to run a adb program on your computer to unlock the bootloader on the phone so I believe that would fall under the category unless it interface with a computer

Comment: It's coneect by a cord to the phone running adb fastboot with commands coming from the computer

Comment: It plainly states except when it interfaces with your computer which it does

Comment: That's the only way to unlock a bootloader on a phone